# Do I need a receptacle in my kitchen peninsula?

Tags: electrical, nec

I am remodeling my kitchen, which includes a peninsula. The area of the peninsula as measured from the wall is 18.7 sqft, so I need 2 receptacles. One of them must be within 2' of the end of the peninsula, so I planned on placing it at the very end. There are no backsplashes/short walls on the three sides of the peninsula. Can I locate the second receptacle on the wall/backsplash, underneath the wall cabinets?

If the answer to this is "yes" because of 210.52(C)(3), my next question is whether I need a receptacle somewhere in the middle of the peninsula. The peninsula is 6' long. This means that an appliance at the midpoint can reach neither the wall (it's 3' away) nor the outlet at the end of the peninsula (that is also 3' away). Does a peninsula without a wall still need to follow the rule about appliances not being more than 24" from a receptacle outlet?

If "yes," and I need an outlet accessible from the midpoint, I'll probably install it underneath the counter, within an open bookshelf. This should be valid per 210.52(C)(3) because it will not be more than 12" vertically from the counter and I will not install it more than 6" deep into the bookshelf. (One of the bookshelves is only 8" deep.)

Here is a quick snippet from my cabinet design. You can see it's 72" long and 32" wide. The wall is at the top of the image. The bookshelves are 8" and 11" deep on the left side of the image. The possible location for an outlet accessible from the midpoint is within the bookshelf that labeled *24"x8"?*. Because a single gang box is probably 3"-4" deep, the outlet would only be 6" from the counter's overhang.

If there are any reminders on dishwasher wiring, I'll take that, too! It's already wired in this location, so hopefully however it's done, I don't need to touch it.

[image]

EDIT:
I've edited my post with current thinking in blue, pink is the path of a grounded electrical cord from the dishwasher. I've reduced the size of the two bookshelves (with doors) on back side of peninsula, so that there is now an empty space between the two with a 3-4" filler piece at the front. I could cut into this front to attach a handy box for the peninsula outlet that must be 24" from the end of the peninsula. I have marked the top of the drawing with thick blue lines where duplex receptacles will exist, one counting for the peninsula and the other two as normal.

The next part I've labeled is for the dishwasher outlet options. It's currently hard-wired, but I've learned that could be a problem because the junction box needs to be accessible. Three options. Option C, where 'C' is labeled on drawing in blue: hard-wire it and locate the junction box here. This is behind a 30" deep drawer in an empty space. Option B, ignore. I just realized the appliance cord would be more than 3-4 feet which I don't think NEC code would allow? But that would have been a duplex 12" from the floor. Option A, not accessible unless I remove the dishwasher, a duplex outlet mounted in/on the floor, appliance cord plugged in there.

Dishwasher question: which placements A-C are valid and code compliant? Do I need a disconnect for Option B, if I can just reach back and unplug it? Can the 12/2 be typical NM cabling, or do I need something protected?

Bonus question: The circuits for the dishwasher and disposal (11+13 at my panel) are multiwire 15A circuits and the breakers do not have GFCI or AFCI protection. What is the best way to make this code compliant? An electrician told me I can't get new breakers because they don't make them for this situation.

Comment: You could install a pop-up outlet on the countertop or modify the design to allow for an outlet near the middle somewhere if It worries you.

Comment: "void?" is the short way of saying "future mouse nest!" ;^)

Comment: I presume this is in MN from your username? (I ask because 250.52(C) on kitchen outlets has gone through some recent revisions)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, I am in MN. What are the changes? My house was built in the early 80s. The kitchen has two 20A circuits, the dishwasher is currently hard-wired on its own circuit, the disposal has its own outlet and circuit under the sink, the gas range and refrigerator each have their own non-GFCI outlet but not on separate circuits. I will need to add two receptacle outlets for the existing countertops (unrelated to peninsula) to meet current code. My 100A panel is full, and none of those breakers are GFCI. GFCI protection is incorporated into the receptacles themselves.

Comment: How do you plan to protect the wiring going into the receptacle box mounted under the bookshelf?  Also, what's over this peninsula? (P.S. [my answer here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/219070/27099) covers various options one can use for peninsula countertop receptacles, including above-the-counter pedestal options)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I should have mentioned the "bookshelf" is a permanently installed kitchen cabinet base. I'd run it off of the load side of a GFCI receptacle at counter height (by "void" in the drawing), along dishwasher where there is space, and then into back of bookshelf-cabinet-thing. Can I use a raised/exposed box to mount it in? If I didn't, and recessed it into the bookshelf's back (there's no room for this, anyway), it would be 8" deep, and code only allows 6" deep under a countertop.

Comment: When you do install an outlet, it might be very nice to use one with USB ports built in.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. I've edited my main post with an updated image, and some updated questions regarding code compliance for the peninsula duplex outlets, code compliance for the dishwasher (comparing one hard-wire and two options leveraging new duplex outlets), as well as trying to figure out what my rules are for a disconnect (is disconnect only for hard-wire?) and cable protection (if I install the duplex outlet in the floor and the NM is not exposed, do I need cable protection)?

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY -- disconnect for a hardwired dishwasher can be handled with a $10 or less lockoff bracket in the breaker panel, no need to make it complicated.  floor outlet in kitchen is probably a bad plan.  I'd use a 2 pole AFCI feeding deadfront GFCIs for your situation with the MWBC btw

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Where does the deadfront GFCI get located? Is this used because there's no such thing as a 2-pole AFCI/GFCI breaker? I had heard of deadfront GFCIs but have not encountered one in use before.

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY -- the deadfront GFCI would be in a kitchen cabinet adjacent to the dishwasher, and yes, its used because  2 pole Dual Function (AF/GF) breakers aren't (yet) a thing

Answer (score 2):

Line of thought 1 - code is minimum, more might be useful in practice.

Line of thought 2 - depending on the exact interpretation of the "2 feet", the "outlet for the middle" could also be "the outlet within 2 feet of the end" if placed correctly.

There are cute pop-up outlet products to go into the countertop, but they are costly and I have to wonder how well they handle a liquid spill.

My interpretation of the language of 252(C)(2)(b)

> (b) At least one receptacle outlet shall be located within 600 mm (2
> ft) of the outer end of a peninsular countertop or work surface.
> Additional required receptacle outlets shall be permitted to be
> located as determined by the installer, designer, or building owner.
> The location of the receptacle outlets shall be in accordance with
> 210.52(C)(3).

Is that other than that one for the end, it's your call. My call is line of thought #1. The "2 foot rule" (252(C)(1) is "horizontally **along the wall**" and the "2 feet from the end" is because that rule wouldn't make use at the end of the peninsula feasible.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to avoid a pop-up product. Even if it's leakproof, I don't want that interrupting the counter or accumulating crumbs. So does code require an outlet in the middle of this peninsula? Or just a total of 2 for the peninsula (one 2' from the end, which I will put at the end, and the other can be at the wall)?

Comment: @MinnesotaDIY - 210.52(C)(2)(a) "A receptacle outlet shall be provided for every additional 1.7 m2 (18 ft2), or fraction thereof, of the countertop or work surface."

Comment: Two is the minimum number, as you already knew, and the language appears to allow one at the wall and one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

One for the first nine square feet of countertop/worktop. One for every additional 18 square feet. And one within two lineal feet of the end.

---

https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=822.0

**N 210.52(C)(2)** Island and Peninsular Countertops and Work Surfaces.

Receptacle outlets shall be installed in accordance with 210.52(C)(2)(a) and (C)(2)(b).

(a) **At least one** receptacle outlet shall be provided **for the first 0.84 m2 (9 ft2)**, or fraction thereof, of the countertop or work surface. A receptacle outlet shall be provided for **every additional 1.7 m2 (18 ft2)**, or fraction thereof, of the countertop or work surface.

(b) **At least one** receptacle outlet shall be **located within 600 mm (2 ft) of the outer end of a peninsular** countertop or work surface. Additional required receptacle outlets shall be permitted to be located as determined by the installer, designer, or building owner. The location of the receptacle outlets shall be in accordance with 210.52(C)(3).

A peninsular countertop shall be measured from the connected perpendicular wall.

Comment: The first two are square feet, the last one is linear feet.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Well that's not helpful at all. So something like, if you have 6' deep counters there should be an outlet every two feet?

Comment: If you have a 6 foot **wide** peninsula, you need one within 2 feet of the end and (numerically) one every 3 feet (after the first foot and a half) but the location of them is left up to *the installer, designer, or building owner. * I.e. you have to have that number, but you can put 7 at the wall and one at the end and meet this language. You might curse your own cleverness later when trying to plug things in, though. *Any* counter over 2 feet deep needs one every 4 feet on the wall - you don't need more for your hypothetical 6 foot deep inconvenient counter, though - except at a peninsula.

Comment: OP's section is 16 square feet. So one at the end and one at the wall. And one for "every additional 1.7 m2 (18 ft2), *or fraction thereof*," ... so, one in the middle too. - Whether the client wants them or not (you *will* want them), this is when and where we have to put in pop-up outlets, +1 @Ecnerwal. - I'd do two; one on each side of the dishwasher. The one on the end is for the vacuum, not cell chargers while sitting at the bar.

Comment: Peninsular area is measured to the wall. Last line of your code quote. That means the "regular countertop" between it and the wall is included in its area. I'll believe the 18.7 from the OP. Which is just two outlets - one for the first 9 square feet, one for the next fraction of 18 (9.7). The one located within 2 feet of the end is not an extra, it's one of the required number based on area.